# LinkedList, bug in get or add

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm creating a linked list and having some problems either in get() or add(index, data). I do believe the add is correct though so I ask you to find what I'm doing wrong in the get() method.
Edit: problem is that I'm getting the same value at index 0 and index 1.

```
public T get(int index) {
        int counter = 0;
        Node<T> temp = head;
        if(index < 0 || index > size() || head == null){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else {
            if(index == size()){
                temp = tail;
                return temp.data;
            }
            if(index == 0){
                return temp.data;
            }  else {
                while (counter +1 != index){
                    temp = temp.next;
                    counter++;
                }
                return temp.data;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's problem?

Comment: I'm getting the same value at index 0 and index 1 but they are different

Comment: Imagine you're passed in index==1 - you'd want the second element, yes?  However, your while loop will never enter (since counter ==0 means counter+1 == index).   So change your while loop to "while (counter < index)".  You'll find you don't need the explicit "if(index==0)" then either :)

Comment: Thank you, that solved my question. I would mark it as solved if I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you're passed in index==1 - you'd want the second element, yes?

However, your while loop will never enter (since counter ==0 means counter+1 == index). 
So change your while loop to "while (counter < index)".

You'll find you don't need the explicit "if(index==0)" then either :)

In fact, this loop then condenses into a straight for loop, so :

```
for (int counter=0; counter < index; counter++) {
    temp = temp.next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in while loop is wrong. You need to change it to-

```
while (counter != index){
   temp = temp.next;
   counter++;
}
```